# Cannot resolve symbol 'LocationService' when trying to add marshmallow permission support

Tags: java, android, permissions, gps, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to create a GPSTracker class I can run from a fragment to get users GPS Location.  I had one running fine except it needed stupid marshmallow permission support (i know it's not stupid i actually like it but it's being a pest right now).

I'm getting two error messages.  one "Cannot resolve symbol 'LocationService' at the line

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                    LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION);
```

and the other "Cannot resolve method 'showAlertDialog(me.paxana.alerta.adapter.GPSTracker, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)'"

at the line

```
public void showAlertDialog(){
        am.showAlertDialog(GPSTracker.this, "GPS Setting", "Gps is not enabled. Do you want to enabled it ?", false);
```

**GPSTracker.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta.adapter;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.afollestad.assent.Assent;
import com.afollestad.assent.Assent.*;
import com.afollestad.assent.AssentActivity;
import com.afollestad.assent.AssentCallback;
import com.afollestad.assent.PermissionResultSet;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements android.location.LocationListener {

    private Context context;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude,longitude;



    LocationManager locationManager;
    AlertDialog.Builder am = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    public GPSTracker(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }
    private Location getLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                    LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION);
        }
        try{
            locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled){

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 3, this);

                    if (locationManager != null){
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null){
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isGPSEnabled){
                    if (location == null){
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 3, this);
                        if (locationManager != null){
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null){
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    showAlertDialog();
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GPSTracker.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(){
        am.showAlertDialog(GPSTracker.this, "GPS Setting", "Gps is not enabled. Do you want to enabled it ?", false);
    }
    public double getLatitude(){
        if (location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if (location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation(){
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null){
            this.location = location;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Edit**

I think i got the second one cleared up by changing it to

```
public void showAlertDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder am = new AlertDialog.Builder(GPSTracker.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        am.setTitle("GPS settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        am.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to enable it?");

        am.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        am.setNegativeButton("No", null);
        am .create().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

At the first error I believe you need only `MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` instead of `LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION`.

As for the second error, by looking at the [API 23 Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html), there is no method `showAlertDialog` in the class `AlertDialog.Builder`.

I believe the correct way to create the dialog would be by using it the same way as in your `showSettingsAlert()` method.

Comment: the first one, when I get rid of LocationService and just make it MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (i noticed a typo course != coarse, which surprisingly wasn't the problem), it then cannot resolve symbol 'MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'

on the second one I see what you're saying,  but i'm not sure what to do on a yes response to that, how to make an intent that turns on GPS

Comment: i think i got the second one figured out thanks for your help with that one

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution from other place,first,just declare a variable:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 11;
```

and use this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
}
```

It's work on me,hope it will help you.